# Not Able To Resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0 depends on libraries but is a jar

Tags: android, android-studio

I had created an Android studio Project in one system and and imported in another system while building the project I am keep on getting this error
I am currently compiling with android SDK 23

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not find play-services-location.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         file:/home/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/7.5.0/play-services-location-7.5.0.jar

Thing tried so far
* Adding dependency in the module level
* Downgrading the SDK to lower version till 21
* Installing Google Play Service library

Please suggest

**Update**
I tried this as well . Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.1.0
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog
    Error:Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1.0
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog
And when I click on install repositories it tells me Error:
"Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-google-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter."

Comment: Install the Google Repository in your SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your gradle file  at the app level and that should include all the google play services which you can use in your application. Read the information in the URL below on what are the services included (location service is one of them).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup